# "drush cc" fails

Tags: drush, caching

Does anyone know why Drush doesn't recognize the Drupal 7 installation when I run `drush cache:clear`?

It gives me the following error message.

> Command cache-rebuild requires Drupal core version 8+ to run.

`drush status` and `drush -d` give me the right root and right configuration.

I installed Drush with `composer require "drush/drush": "7.x-dev"`.

Comment: What does `which drush` and `drush --version` return you? You also should better use Drush 8. `composer require drush/drush:^8.0`.

Answer (score 1):

As @leymannx said in the comments you should better use drush 8 since it's the recommended version for a drupal 7 site (https://www.drush.org/install/#drupal-compatibility).

If `drush --version` returns something else than `7.x-dev` it means you're using another drush than the one you think. You can go in your website `/web` directory and execute `../vendor/bin/drush cc` to use the one you installed for this project.